# Make the active list on top of the list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I have a list of items using `ng-repeat`.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="">{{item.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Whenever I click on any item of the generated list, it gets the class of active.

Now can someone please let me know how can I make the active item goes on top of the list.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean `make the active item goes on top of the list.` ? you reffer to action of make default active item?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut after I click on any item of the list, it gets a class of active and I want that active class item to be on top of the list.

Comment: Now i understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a property *active* in your item, order your item by this property, handle *click* event and set *active* to true for clicked item only:

```
ul>
    <li ng-click="onClick(item)" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : 'active': false"><a href="">{{item.name}}</a></li>
</ul>

$scope.onClick = function(item) {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(it) {
        it.active = it.id === item.id;
    });
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Wouldn't it be better to use map() instead of forEach()? In terms of speed that is.

Comment: @KristjánJóel map is not necessary here because we don't use the transformed array that it returns. We simply change the active property for each item and forEach is enough to do that

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind a `click` eventr handler using `ng-click` directive.

Then you just need to `reorder` the order of your given list.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="clickItem(item)" ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="">{{item.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.clickItem = function(item){
   //get item
   var obj = $scope.items.find(a => a.id == item.id);
   //remove item from list
   $scope.items = $scope.items.filter(i => i.id != item.id);
   //add item at beggining of the array
   $scope.items.unshift(obj);
}
```